# Magento 2 - Collections vs Repositories

Tags: magento2

Please explain what is the difference between collections and repositories.

1. What is the difference between those two?
2. Which shall I use in custom module?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Collections**

- During   development,    if  working with    collections that    have    lot of  attributes, filters,    and
  possibly a   future  large   dataset,    we  might   want    to  use SQL logging to  record  actual  SQL
  queries  hitting the database    server.
- This might   help    us  spot    possible    performance
  bottlenecks  and react   on  time,   either  by  adding  more    limiting    values  to  setPageSize     or addAttributeToSelect ,   or  both.

**Repositories**

- when you use repositories you adhere to Magento 2 service contracts,
  which means that service interfaces and data interfaces are defined
  (but extensible by third-party modules).
- Making it possible at run-time to change the result of the call to
  the getList() method of a repository.
- To retrieve the attributes you need at run-time you can use
  collections. Magento 2 framework itself makes an heavy use of
  collections.
- Otherwise you should implement a module which defines a new data
  interface (that is, the new set of attributes) for that entity.

> So Both we can use on our priority and our flexiblity.